# How do I pass a variable to a childController of UINavigationController based on the selected UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop, uinavigationcontroller

Imagine a simple Navigation based iPhone app. 
The top level is a tableView with cells that read "PDF1" "PDF2" "PDF3" with disclosure indicators. Let's call the top level controller "RootController."

When you push the cell labelled "PDF1" a child controller class called "PDFViewerController" is pushed onto the stack which builds a new screen and loads "PDF1" in it's UIWebView.

Now imagine we go back to the tableView and push the tableCell "PDF2." This time the same "PDFViewerController" is pushed onto the stack but now it knows to load "PDF2".

The way I'm doing it now I have to write controller classes for PDF1, PDF2 and PDF3 creatively named "PDFViewerController1","PDFViewerController2","PDFViewerController3".
The thing is the only difference in these classes is the NSURL and it would be much less redundant code to be able to pass in the right NSURL based on a tableCell selection.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about OOP here. It'd be great if someone could point me in the right direction. I'm not even sure what kind of string to google to solve this. If someone can suggest a better title for this thread that might help others too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an init method for PDF view controller with an extra parameter, then, in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
PDFViewController *pdfvc = [[PDFViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PDFViewController" bundle:nil andURL:(NSURL *)[myURLS objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:pdfvc animated:YES];
[pdfvc release];
```

Comment: Awesomeness! Thank You! It seems so obvious now. =)